# how do i show date picker when clicked on textfield

Tags: ios, swift

> this is my code

```
- @IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var txt2: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var txt3: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var txt4: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var txt5: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var txt6: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var txt7: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!


   var category = ["Male", "Female", "Others"]

   let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       picker.isHidden = true

       txt3.delegate = self

       self.txt3.inputView = picker

       //txt3.inputView  = category[row]
   }

   // returns the # of rows in each component..
   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
       return category.count
   }

   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
       return category[row]
   }

   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
   {
       txt3.text = category[row]
      // category.isHidden = true;
   }

   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       if textField == txt3 {
           //resignFirstResponder()
           //picker.isHidden = true
                 }
       return true
       }
   }


   @IBAction func txt3(_ sender: Any) {
       func showDatePicker(){
           //Formate Date
           datePicker.datePickerMode = .date


           //ToolBar
           let toolbar = UIToolbar();
           toolbar.sizeToFit()

           //done button & cancel button
           let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action:
  Selector(("donedatePicker")))
           //let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
          // let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action:
   Selector("cancelDatePicker"))
           toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

           // add toolbar to textField
           txt3.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
           // add datepicker to textField
           txt3.inputView = datePicker

       }

       func donedatePicker(){
           //For date formate
           let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
           txt3.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
           //dismiss date picker dialog
           self.view.endEditing(true)
       }

       func cancelDatePicker(){
           //cancel button dismiss datepicker dialog
           self.view.endEditing(true)
       }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: what the issue u faced

Comment: it doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   picker.isHidden = true
   txt3.delegate = self
   //self.txt3.inputView = picker // don't do this 
   self.txt3.inputView = datePicker // do like this.
   let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButton))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButton)
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    txt3.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

func doneButton(){
    let selectedDate  = datePicker.date
    print(selectedDate)
    txt3.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

It will automatically open the date picker.

Comment: @SeasiaCreativeCrew now you can try updated answer it'll select a date also.In this i m giving done and cancel same action you can mange a/c to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt3.inputView = picker
```

and remove

```
picker.isHidden = true
```

This should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

first, you add this..

```
txt3.inputView = picker
```

then you add

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   if textField == txt3 {
          picker.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        picker.isHidden = true
    }
   return true
}
```

Comment: question is related to datepicker not pickerview, he used both on same textfield,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik in the question the user is using uipickerview only one textfield